# Pandas DataFrame Self-Join on Key1 == Key1 and Key2 +1 == Key2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to alter a key during `pandas.merge()`?

I'm trying to join `data` to itself on `left.person == right.person` and `left.record +1 == right.record`, so I can fill delta with datetime difference `right.date - left.date`.

I'm on `Python 3.5.1 | IPython 4.1.2 | Anaconda custom (64-bit) | Windows 7`

```
In[38]: data.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 11185856 entries, 0 to 11185855
Data columns (total 4 columns):
person    int64
record    int64
date      datetime64[ns]
delta     datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), int64(2)
memory usage: 341.4 MB

In[39]: data.head(5)
Out[37]: 
   person  record       date delta
0       1       1 2015-08-01   NaT
1       1       2 2015-10-18   NaT
2       1       3 2016-02-06   NaT
3       2       1 2015-04-18   NaT
4       2       2 2015-07-11   NaT
```

This was trivial for me in SQL, but after reading pages of pandas-docs on merging and concatenation I'm still not getting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are definitely a lot of ways to tackle this problem. One way, if a bit clumsy, would be to create a new column and merge onto that, i.e.:

```
df.loc[:,'RecordOffset'] = df.record + 1
df = df.merge(df, left_on = ['person', 'record'], right_on = ['person', 'RecordOffset'], how = 'left')
```

Another way to do this might be a pivot, for example:

```
import datetime
df = pd.DataFrame({'person':[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3],
                  'record':[1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3],
                  'date' : [datetime.date(2015, 8, i) for i in range(1,9 )]})

df.pivot('person', 'record', 'date')
```

Yields:

```
record           1           2           3
person                                    
1       2015-08-01  2015-08-02  2015-08-03
2       2015-08-04  2015-08-05         NaN
3       2015-08-06  2015-08-07  2015-08-08
```

Comment: Is there any way to modify a key within the merge function, like `pd.merge(left, right, left_on=key, right_on=key+1`?

Comment: I am not aware of any way to do this, however, if you are interested I can show you some ways to execute pure SQL with dataframes. It can be slower (since it needs to invlove a database), but if you are proficient with SQL it might benefit you.